# Multiple UIImageViews with UIImagePicker

Tags: ios6, uiimagepickercontroller, xcode4.5

I am brand new to using UIImagePicker so bear with me here. Basically, I have two UIButtons defined that access the camera roll and once an image is chosen, the image appears in my UIImageView. The problem is when I choose an image from one of the buttons, it appears in both UIImageViews, and not one. I basically want to be able to choose two different photos by means of two different buttons. Here is the coding:

```
-(IBAction)getPhoto1:(id)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    popover1 = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
    [popover1 presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 400., 400.0) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

}

-(IBAction)getPhoto2:(id)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    popover2 = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
    [popover2 presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 400.0, 400.0) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    photo1.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    photo2.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` is called whenever you finish selecting an image.

When the you finish selecting an image from the `UIImagePickerController`, you are setting both `UIImageView` to the image returned.

You need to differentiate between which button has been pressed - perhaps you could use a `int` to determine which button was pressed.

For example, create an 'int' called `buttonPressed` that'll be set to `1` when `getPhoto1` was pressed, or `2` when `getPhoto2` was pressed.  Then, in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`, you could have:

```
if (buttonPressed == 1) {
    photo1.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
} else if (buttonPressed == 2) {
    photo2.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this ended up working great. I set an int above the actions: int buttonSelect = 0; Then set it to 1 and 2 in the different actions and it worked great. Thank you!